# NMOS Switch, Drain Source Location

Tags: mosfet, switches

I just have a bit of confusion about which way to orient MOSFETs in IC switches for sample and hold circuits

[image]

**Which one is it? Or does it not matter?**, since the Source and Drain potentials will be quite similar anyways. Accoutning for the device Ron, then Vin should be a tiny bit higher than Vout.

Comment: some MOSFETS are symmetric; some (especially high voltage) have special structures on the channels or drains;

Comment: Is this a discrete element circuit, or part of a larger IC design?

Comment: @ThePhoton IC design.

Answer (score 1):

If you are designing circuits at the IC level then your MOSFETs will be four-terminal devices and there is no physical difference between the source/drain terminals.

Most importantly this means that the body of the transistor need not be connected to the source. In fact, the body of all NMOS transistors is usually connected to the lowest voltage in the device, often ground. In this case the "source" of an NMOS transistor will be the terminal with the **lower** voltage and the "drain" terminal will be the one with the higher voltage.

Comment: In this case though, The higher voltage is the Vin node, so how come some people draw the source connected to the Vin node rather than Vout node? What do I assume they have connected their body to?

Comment: usually the body will be connected to either the more negative of the source/drain, or to some guaranteed-more-negative than source or drain.

Comment: In VLSI digital design, the bodies of many, many transistors are a common n-well, p-well, or the substrate itself. The sources of these transistors will be a different potentials so it is not possible, in general, to connect these sources to the body. The body will therefore be connected to the most negative voltage (NMOS) or most positive voltage (PMOS) in the circuit, so that reverse-bias isolation is maintained for all transistor sources.